# A curious email

Tags: steganography

You are a secret agent who is undercover at the Kremlin. You receive a cryptic email (presumably from your boss) who was supposed to give you the code name of the agent who would be picking you up from the airport to bring you back home. As a sidenote, you are aware that most agent names are animals.

> From: apres_abcde@let.ter
> To: me
> Subject: Banana Bread
>
> Dear Person,
> I am pleased to inform you that your banana bread's CV is exemplary if it is denied a position at its current job.
>
> Sincerely,
> ABCDE

So who is the agent that will pick you up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The agents name is

> Raven

Because

> We look at ABCDE. Go to the first occurence of A within the *body* of the mail,  take the next character, which is R. Then continue from the current position to the next occurence of B, take the next letter (a), and so on

Comment: Amazing! This is correct!

Comment: Note that the email address has a French word which clues this pattern, too!

Comment: @El-Guest -- Yep! Après = after so "after ABCDE!" Nice catch. :):)